# Are hospitality industry questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just started an [Area 51 proposal for people working in the hospitality industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86541/hospitality-industry) and I was wondering if questions dealing with restaurant management, menu balancing, food cost, and so on were already on-topic here.

Pretty much just checking if these bases are already covered or if there may be some interest in covering them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, we don't generally take questions about the business aspects of making food, just the culinary ones. I'm sure there would end up being some overlap, but we definitely don't cover it all. (Your two example questions are off topic here, to start with.)

Whether or not that means there's enough interest to get a hospitality site going, I don't know!